# One click on mouseover

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a simple javascript mouseover event to fire a c# click event on asp menu, it works fine, but when I enter the menuitem, the click event is fired infinite times. I want it to fire only once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".div1").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).click();
})
.mouseleave(function () {
    $("#Menu1").remove();
    $("#Menu2").remove();
    $("#Menu3").remove();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in two ways:

First way:

```
$(".div1").mouseover(function () {
    $(this)
        .click()
        .off('mouseover'); // Unbind the mouseover once we triggered the click
})
```

Second way - using ".one" binding which triggers the event handling only once

```
$(".div1").one('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).click();
})
```

Comment: It must work, you should give us more detailed code or even better a jsFiddle displaying the issue itself.

Comment: I can't write the c# click event in jsFiddle, I don't even know if it's possible, but I'm pretty sure the jQuery call for it is the problem.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle, prove of the concept - fully working : http://jsfiddle.net/XXLgX/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var done = false;
$('.div1').mouseover(function()
{
    if(!done)
    {
        $(this).click();
        done = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) jQuery's function :

```
var fireClick = function () {
    $(this).click();
    $(this).unbind('mouseover');
};

$(".div1").mouseover(fireClick)
.mouseleave(function () {
    $("#Menu1").remove();
    $("#Menu2").remove();
    $("#Menu3").remove();
    $(this).mouseover(fireClick);
});
```